# How to get the value of the static properties of a child class in the parent class?

Tags: php, oop

I have several models with this structure:

```php
class Test extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static string $defaultDateRange = 'month'; // This property is the same in all classes
    public static array $fields = ['name', 'price']; // This property is unique for each class

    // This function is the same in all classes
    public static function batchUpdate(array $preparedData): int
    {
        // A class variable is used here - self::$fields
    }

    // This function is different in all classes
    public static function prepareData(array $data): array
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Models have both common properties and functions, and their own unique ones. I want to optimize the code to remove duplicate code sections, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried to create a base class and define all the duplicate properties and methods in it. But I can't get the value of the property of the child element **Test::$fields** in any way.

```php
class BaseMarketplaceMetric extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static string $defaultDateRange = 'month';

    public static function batchUpdate(array $preparedData): int
    {
        // Need access to a property of a child class - Test::$fields
    }
}


class Test extends BaseMarketplaceMetric
{
    public static array $fields = ['name', 'price'];

    public static function prepareData(array $data): array
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do I get the value of the static properties of a child class in the parent class? Or does it all need to be done in a completely different way?

Comment: I just tested it in the REPL and I got the array out of `Test::$fields`. What do you get?

Comment: The question in your title differs from the questions in the text. Can you make them clearer?

Comment: @Geoffrey If write like this `Test::$fields`, then I will get the value. But the fact is that there are several classes like Test and I can't bind to a specific Test class.

Comment: @daniilsidorov, please add the code of how you are trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

I just used `static::$fields` in parent class to get static properties of child classes.