# static function of parent class using child class values

Tags: php, oop

I'm creating a library.

My goal is to make the library so easy to use that it doesn't require a lot of programming knowledge and that the system architect can generate its code. **(Low-Code Library)**

Some of my functions are static, because I should call them by `call_user_func()` or any methods that could run a function of a class with string only parameters and without any argument.

My problem is that I want to put the body code of the static function inside the library, and the classes that I inherit from in the code will execute the same function code but with the values of the inherited class.

I also want the inherited classes to require minimal changes and in most cases just defining the values in them is sufficient.

In the library, I used class, abstract class, interface, and taint and defined the values as const and static variables. But none of the cases could help.

Here is a simplified example of my code of **library**:

```php
class ParentClass { // OR abstract class OR interface OR trait
    public const TABLE = 'placeholder'; // OR public static $TABLE = 'placeholder'; OR remove this line!

    public static function save() {
        echo "saving " . self::TABLE . ' ...' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    // and a lot of same functions...
}
```

and here is a simplified example of my code of **main code**:

```php
class ChildClass extends /* OR implements (for interface) */ ParentClass {
    // use ParentClass; (for trait)

    public const TABLE = 'users'; // OR public static $TABLE = 'users'; (using static variable)
}

call_user_func(['ChildClass', 'save']);
// ChildClass::save();
```

**Errors:**

using `trait` and `static variable`; error: ChildClass and ParentClass define the same property ($TABLE)

using `trait` and `const`; error: Traits cannot have constants

using `abstract class` or `class` with `static variable` or `const`; I got 'placeholder' not 'users'

using `interface`; error: Interface function ParentClass::save() cannot contain body

using `interface` and `static variable`; error: Interfaces may not include properties

Comment: While the linked questions are relevant, they aren't really _duplicates_, and I certainly disagree with whoever cast a negative vote on both question and answer here. The first two questions start with knowing that the `static` keyword exists, and ask what it does; this question starts with _wanting_ that behvaiour, but having no reason to know what it would be called. The third link asks about some observed behaviour, not any desire for LSB. This is a perfectly reasonable question, and while I admit I didn't search for duplicates, I wouldn't have found or counted any of those three if I had.

Comment: The _answer_  the question exists in the dupe targets. That's what dupes are for.  Numbers 3, 4 and 5 weren't found looking for "late static binding", but looking for keywords present in this question. Number 5 by searching for the title directly. It's perfectly fine the OP didn't know the right keywords. The hope is that someone that knows better would lead them to the right target, instead of posting yet another answer to yet another duplicate, @IMSoP.

Comment: @yivi Out of those five, I would only count one as an actual duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2430348/ (and its top answer is pretty rubbish, but the next one down is OK). Of the others, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69327030/ should just be closed as a dupe itself (and I have), and the others are all *asking different questions*. I personally don't agree with downvoting good-faith answers on rare duplicates, but am not that bothered; I feel it's very harsh to downvote the *question* though.

Comment: @IMSoP Again, the answer to this "issue" exists in **all** the linked questions. Here there are two more that are found searching for this question's title, in the first 5 results: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774612/access-child-class-static-variables-from-parent-class) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678466/how-do-i-call-a-static-child-function-from-parent-static-function). The dupe editor doesn't allow for more, though. A cursory search, just using these keywords, is surely to produce more results.

Comment: @yivi We'll have to agree to disagree about the other feedback, but I've edited the duplicate list to the two questions that actually talk about the scenarios the OP was asking about. Let's concentrate on actually helping the user, not showing off how many slightly related questions Stack Overflow has built up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fancy term for what you're trying to do is ["Late Static Binding"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

> Static references to the current class like self:: or **CLASS** are resolved using the class in which the function belongs, as in where it was defined ...
>
> Late static bindings tries to solve that limitation by introducing a keyword that references the class that was initially called at runtime.

You can read the full details on the linked manual page, but the short answer is that instead of `self::` you need to write `static::`. This works with both class constants and static properties:

```
class ParentClass { // whether it's abstract or not makes no difference
    public const TABLE = 'fallback_const_if_wanted';
    public static string $table = 'fallback_var_if_wanted';

    public static function demo() {
       echo 'self::TABLE is ', self::TABLE, "\n";
       echo 'self::$table is ', self::$table, "\n";
       echo 'static::TABLE is ', static::TABLE, "\n";
       echo 'static::$table is ', static::$table, "\n";
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public const TABLE = 'child_const';
    public static string $table = 'child_var';
}

ChildClass::demo();
```

As you can see on this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/CblZr), the result is:

```
self::TABLE is fallback_const_if_wanted
self::$table is fallback_var_if_wanted
static::TABLE is child_const
static::$table is child_var
```

If you don't define the values in the parent class, you'll get an error using `self::` but `static::` will still resolve correctly:

```
abstract class ParentClass {
    public static function demo() {
       echo 'static::TABLE is ', static::TABLE, "\n";
       echo 'static::$table is ', static::$table, "\n";
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public const TABLE = 'child_const';
    public static string $table = 'child_var';
}

ChildClass::demo();
```

[Gives](https://3v4l.org/6TkfF):

```
static::TABLE is child_const
static::$table is child_var
```